# validates_uniqueness_of with a 'has_many through =>' relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

Below, I have a TicketMarket model where admins maintain 'market' names.   This table is linked to a ticket table through an association table.

I need there to be a "validates_uniqueness_of" for the TicketMarket CRUD, but as it is below, it will cause validation errors when someone is creating a ticket and check some market checkboxes on the ticket form.

Everythign I've seen says the correct thing to do is to scope the validation based on the "ticket_id" field of the "ticket_market_associations" table:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :market_name, :case_sensitive => false, :scope => :ticket_id
```

However, that doesn't work.  With that scope in place, working with the TicketMarket CRUD results in a "undefined method `ticket_id' for #TicketMarket:0x630bdf0" error.

Whats the right thing to do here so the validations only go off when working with the TicketMarket CRUD and not the Ticket CRUD?

Thanks!

```
class TicketMarket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ticket_market_associations
  has_many :tickets, :through => :ticket_market_associations

  validates_presence_of :market_name
  validates_uniqueness_of :market_name, :case_sensitive => false
end
```

Comment: You can put a clustered index on the joins table. `create_index :ticket_market_associations, %i[market_id ticket_id], unique: true` and follow it up with the uniqueness scope validation on the joins model. This will ensure that the ticket id is only taken by one market.